# CompletionService without regular polling

Tags: java, multithreading

Use case: tasks are generated in one thread, need to be distributed for computation to many threads and finally the generating task shall reap the results and mark the tasks as done.

I found the class `ExecutorCompletionService` which fits the use case nearly perfectly --- except that I see no good solution for non-idle waiting. Let me explain.

In principle my code would look like

```
while (true) {
  MyTask t = generateNextTask();
  if (t!=null) {
    completionService.submit(t);
  }
  MyTask finished;
  while (null!=(finished=compService.poll())) {
    retireTaks(finished);
  }
}
```

Both, `generateNextTask()` and `completionService.poll()` may return `null` if there are currently no new tasks available and if currently no task has returned from the CompletionService respectively.

In these cases, the loop degenerates into an ugly idle-wait. I could `poll()` with a timeout or add a `Thread.sleep()` for the double-`null` case, but I consider this a bad workaround, because it nevertheless wastes CPU and is not as responsive as possible, due to the wait.

Suppose I replace `generateNextTask()` by a `poll()` on a `BlockingQueue`, is there good way to poll the queue as well as the `CompletionService` in parallel to be woken up for work on whichever end something becomes available?

Actually this reminds me of `Selector`. Is something like it available for queues?

Comment: Why not take instead of poll?

Comment: why generateNextTask() can return null? Are tasks taken from outer world?

Comment: let tasks care of themselves - wrap task in a Runnable whose run() method calls run() of wrapped task and then calls retireTaks().

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov: indeed, from the outer world. And no, I would prefer to clean up after tasks in one central place. Generation and cleanup depend on each other, so if it is done all in one thread, no inter-trhead communication is necessary.

Comment: @assylias because `take` blocks, which would prevent further tasks to be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CompletionService.take()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html#take%28%29) to wait until the next task completes and retrieve its Future. poll() is the non-blocking version, returning null if no task is currently completed.

Also, your code seems to be inefficient, because you produce and consume tasks one at a time, instead of allowing multiple tasks to be processed in parallel. Consider having a different thread for task generation and for task results consumption.

**-- Edit --**

I think that given the constraints you mention in your comments, you can't achieve all your requirements. 
Requiring the main thread to be producer and consumer, and disallowing any busy loop or timed loop, you can't avoid the scenario where a blocking wait for a task completion takes too long and no other task gets processed in the meanwhile.

Comment: Then I would only ever have 1 task in-flight. The intention is to have many tasks in flight. And I have a potentially never ending sequence of tasks, so I have to switch between submitting and collecting results. Therefore blocking to wait for a task to finish is not an option.

Comment: @Harald: If you use a ThreadPoolExecutor behind the CompletionService, then you don't have to switch anything; the pooled threads perform the work, and one additional thread collects the results as they arrive and processes them.

Comment: This does not help. If there is no more task in-flight (in the completionService) `take` would block forever and no new tasks would be submitted. On the other hand, if I block in generateNextTask, meanwhile tasks might finish and I should take the result and finish up the task immediately.

Comment: @Harald: you should first decide what's the stopping criteria. If the tasks creator determines it's time to stop, it has to raise a flag and interrupt the consumer thread, which in turn should finish its remaining work and exit. Note that take() is Interruptible.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to *not* have different threads for task generation and consumption.

Comment: @Harald: Are the tasks given in advance? if so, submit them all (which is a non blocking operation), and then proceed with looping on take(). This is the classic scenario...

Comment: please see my first comment to your answer: "potentially never ending sequence of tasks".

Comment: @Harald: Then you could process them in chunks (e.g. create until nothing is available and then loop on take(), with an exact iteration count).

Comment: Of the 10 tasks of a chunk, 9 might finish in 1 second, while one of them takes 1 hour. During that 1 hour, the process is blocked in the `take()` while in fact it could submit and clean up thousands of tasks. Blocking is not an option, neither on the create-side, nor on the clean up side. That's why I am asking for a kind of `Selector`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you "can replace generateNextTask() by a poll() on a BlockingQueue", I assume incoming tasks can be put in a queue by some other thread, and the problem is, you cannot execute `take()` on 2 queues simultaneously. The solution is to simply put both incoming and finished tasks in the same queue. To differentiate, wrap them in objects of different types, and then check that type in the loop after take().

This solution works, but we can go further. You said you don't want to use 2 threads for handling tasks - then you can use zero threads. Let wrappers implement Runnable and, instead of checking of the type, you just call `take().run()`. This way your thread become a single-threaded `Executor`. But we already have an Executor (CompletionService), can we use it? The problem is, handling of incoming and finished tasks should be done serially, not in parallel. So we need `SerialExecutor` described in [api/java/util/concurrent/Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), which accepts Runnables and executes them serially, but on another executor. This way no thread is wasted.

And finally, you mentioned Selector as possible solution. I must say, it is an outdated approach. Learn dataflow and actor computing. Nice introduction is [here](http://blog.xcelerit.com/dataflow-an-effective-model-for-high-performance-computing-2/). Look at [Dataflow4java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/tree/master/df4j-core) project of mine, it has [MultiPortActorTest.java](https://github.com/rfqu/df4j2/blob/master/df4j-core/test/org/df4j/core/actor/MultiPortActorTest.java) example, where class `Accum` does what you need, with all the boilerplate with wrapper Runnables and serial executors hidden in the supporting library.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `ListenableFuture` from Guava. [ListenableFutureExplained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained)